# Why isn't my :hover working in bootstrap container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My issue is that while the a tag is in the container the ":hover +" does not work. If I move the a tag outside the container it works fine. Using a basic div instead of the bootstrap container produces the correct result. Is there something that blocks this from happening in the bootstrap libraries?

HTML :

```
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <a href="#" class="test" id="tst">test</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="info">
          <h1>Info</h1>
          <div class="info-box">
            <div class="one">one</div>
            <div class="two">two</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS :
.

```
info{
  text-align:center;
}
.info-box{
  width: 70%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.one, .two{
  display: none;
}


a:hover  .container 
> .row > .col-sm-4
> .info > .info-box 
>.one{
  display: block;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Froy/pen/LGQMyo)

Comment: `+` is a sibling selector. The link is not a sibling of `.container`.

Comment: Can you show me an example? I removed the + but it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to happen? What element do you want to hover and what happens when you hover?

Comment: If the user hovers over the a tag the div with class="one" should appear(using display: block;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the element that you want to show when you hover over the tag is NOT a child of the element your are hovering over, it's not going to be possible to target the element via CSS.

Your best bet is to use some very simple javascript/jquery.

Since you are using Bootstrap, I'm going to assume you are loading jQuery.

Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrMPXY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.test').hover(function() {
      $('.one').toggle();
    });
});
```

Let's look at what the jQuery is doing. The first line simply says "when the page is loaded, do this..."

In the second line, we start by grabbing the element with a class of "test". You could also target something with an id using $('#test'). Now that we have that element, we want to tell it to do something when we hover over it.

The third line starts with the element we want to do something with, in this case the element with a class of "one". The "toggle" function is a simple shortcut to hide/show. You also could use the hide() function, show() function, or fun things like slideUp(), slideDown(), or slideToggle().

That's it. Let me know if you have anymore questions regarding the jQuery. I have no idea how familiar you are with it so I apologize if this is all obvious.

The only CSS you need is a default state of "display:none;" on the elements you want to hide and show via jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If you looking for only `css` solution, you have to `col-sm-8:hover`

```
.col-sm-8:hover + .col-sm-4 > .info > .info-box > .one {
  display: block;
}
```

in this case you might reduce width of `col-sm-8` block. I just added `float` to this class, you can have another solution!

```
.col-sm-8 {
  float: left;
}
```

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/3jakbp1x/)